# Python scripting

Tags: python, cgi

I have been following along in Programming Python 4th Edition.  One of the tasks is to write a web page that uses cgi to call a python script.  It all seems simple enough, but rather than run the script, the browser echos the script instead.  I think it may be related to the shebang but I am not sure.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Interactive Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method=POST action="cgi-bin/cgi101.py">
            <p><b>Enter your name</b></p>
            <p><input type=text name=user /></p>
            <p><input type=submit title=Submit /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The script:

```
#!python

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
print('<title>Reply Page</title>')
if not 'user' in form:
    print('<h1>Who are you?</h1>')
else:
    print('<h1>Hello <i>%s</i></h1>' % cgi.escape(form['user'].value))
```

Instead of a new page showing "Hello *Tim*"  I'm getting a new page with the script dumped into it.

Comment: a typical shebang is `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Where is the reference to your HTML (the one you have show above)?

Comment: @AdamSmith They might be on Windows where it doesn't matter.

Comment: @SethMMorton yeah that's why I wrote it as a comment instead of an answer. I was directly responding to OP's "I think it may be related to the shebang but I am not sure."

Answer (score 0):

This is an Apache configuration issue that I have not quite worked through.  Now when I run it, I get a file not found error from Apache.  Progress I guess...

Comment: Consider editing your question not posting an answer